# Tangent space of Sym(n,$\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to compute the tangent space of the space of symmetric real matrices Sym(n,$\mathbb{R}$) = $\{A\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})|A^t=A\}$. There are two different (and seemingly contradictory) statements that I have found.

1) In a book it is stated the following

> The tangent space of Sym(n,$\mathbb{R}$) at any point is canonically isomorphic to Sym(n,$\mathbb{R}$) itself, because Sym(n,$\mathbb{R}$) is a vector space.

(does anyone have a reference to a proof that the tangent space of a vector space is canonically isomorphic to the vector space itself?)

2) I tried to obtain the same result in the standard way as follows: for a point $A\in Sym(n,\mathbb{R})$ and a vector $X \in T_ASym(n,\mathbb{R})$ we can find a path $\gamma(s)\in Sym(n,\mathbb{R}) \forall s$, s.t. $\gamma(0)=A$ and $\dot\gamma(0)=X$. Then $\forall s$ we get
$$
  \gamma(s)^t=\gamma(s)\Rightarrow\gamma(s)^t\gamma(s)^{-1}=id
$$
we differentiate the last equation with respect to s at $s=0$ and get
$$
  X^tA^{-1} + A^tX^{-1}=0
$$
In particular, for $A=id$, i.e. for the tangent space at the identity, we get
$$
X^t = -X^{-1}
$$
which is not the same result obtained in 1). Can someone resolve this conundrum?

EDIT: as pointed out below by user1551, the problem in 2) is that I missed to take into consideration that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(s)^{-1} = -\gamma(s)^{-1}\dot\gamma(s)\gamma(s)^{-1}
$$
using this it immediately follows that
$$
X^t = X
$$
In accordance with 1).
If additionally someone told me, to which extent the tangent space of a vector space is canonically isomorphic to the vector space itself, then I would be perfectly happy!

Comment: $Sym(n, \mathbb R)$ defined this way is not an vector space. In particular, the zero matrix is not in $Sym(n, \mathbb R)$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}\gamma^{-1}(t)$ is not $\dot{\gamma}(t)^{-1}$, but $-\gamma(t)^{-1}\dot{\gamma}(t)\gamma(t)^{-1}$. See [planetmath.org](http://planetmath.org/derivativeofinversematrix) for instance.

Comment: Thanks user1551, that was really stupid from my side to have missed that point!

Comment: Thanks John for pointing this out. Maybe one should rather define $Sym(n,\mathbb{R})$ as a subspace of $Mat(n,\mathbb{R})$. Then the zero matrix is in $Sym(n,\mathbb{R})$ and it becomes a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Stan: If so, it does not make sense to consider $\gamma^{-1}$.

Comment: All the calculations hold only for non-degenerated matrices.